# I can't find ndiswrapper on the dvd

Tags: mediatek

I have installed ubuntu as a dual boot with windows and need ndiswrapper to get my network card driver working. The help page says I can find this on the boot cd but I have absolutely no idea where it is. Have looked in every file but no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can find ndiswrapper on both ...

- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+package/ndiswrapper)
- [Packages.ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ndiswrapper&searchon=names)

---

But you are probably wrong: mediatek offers officially support for kernel 3.13 and 3.14. There is a community addition for kernel 4.4

On [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300107&page=2&p=13379155#post13379155) are instructions for a mediatek MT7630E with kernel 4.4.

---

You can find the driver on [github](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E). Download it, extract it and execute (assuming Downloads):

```
cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-release   
sudo chmod +x install
sudo ./install
```

inside the directory you got when extracting it. Wifi should show up in networkmanager and bluetooth should also be available.

If you need more help or more info also have a look at [neurobin](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/issues)'s github page.